# BFS and correctness on the term "VISITED"

Tags: algorithm, breadth-first-search

```
mark x as visited
list L = x
tree T = x
while L nonempty
    choose some vertex v from front of list
    process v
    for each unmarked neighbor w
        mark w as visited
        add it to end of list
        add edge vw to T
```

Most of the code will choose to mark the adjacent node as visited before visiting them. Won't it technically be correct to add all neighbor first and visit them later?

```
list L = x
tree T = x
while L nonempty
    choose some vertex v from front of list
    if (V NOT YET VISITD)
        MARK V AS VISITED HERE
        for each unmarked neighbor w
            add it to end of list
            add edge vw to T
```

Why is it that every BFS seems to mark node as visited when you did not even visit them yet? I am trying to find a theoretically correct code for BFS. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3):

Both algorithms work, but the second version might add the same node to the list L twice. This doesn't affect correctness because of the additional check whether a node was visited, but it increases memory consumption and requires an extra check. That's why you'll typically see the first algorithm in text books.

Comment: Re: "the second version might add the same node to the list L twice": Or more than twice. In the extreme case, if the graph is a complete graph with *n* vertices, then one vertex will be added once, one twice, one thrice, etc., all the way up through one vertex that's added (*n* - 1) times. So an algorithm that's supposed to be linear in the number of vertices is instead quadratic.

Comment: @ruakh Right, but it's only space complexity that suffers. Time complexity for a complete graph is always quadratic in the number of vertices, because the number of edges is already quadratic.

Comment: Good point. (Thinking about it, the `for each unmarked neighbor w` bit must really mean `for each neighbor w` plus `if w is unmarked`.)

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, but they use different definitions of the word `visited`. It is common for algorithms to have many variations and have many different implementations that are all correct, and BFS is one example.